# Format cells in embedded excel using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office

Is there a JavaScript API to format cells in an embedded excel file ? We are able to format the cells via the EWS DOM API but that seems unstable and browser dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely possible.  Here are some examples.

```
function Format1() {
    var tableData = new Office.TableData();
    Office.select("bindings#MyTableXXX").setFormatsAsync(
                [

                //row 1
                { cells: { row: 0, column: 2 }, format: { alignHorizontal: "right", fontSize: 15 } },

                //row 2
                { cells: { row: 1, column: 0 }, format: { numberFormat: "dd-mmm-yy", fontStyle: "bold" } }, 
                { cells: { row: 1, column: 1 }, format: { fontColor: "red", fontStyle: "bold", numberFormat: "#,###.00", borderColor: "blue" } },

                //row 3
                { cells: { row: 2 }, format: { height: 30 } },

                //Whole table: 'Office.Table.All', 'Office.Table.Data' (no headers) and 'Office.Table.Headers'
                { cells: Office.Table.All, format: { borderStyle: "dotted" } },

                ],
        function (asyncResult) {

            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage('Error Format1: ' + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            }
            else {
                writeToPage('Table cell formats changed', 1);
            }
        });
}
```

For more information see www.microsoft-office-add-ins.com